# How to count the number of data being inserted into a form

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on a project which I need to decide if the student inserted into the database has coronavirus or not , and I have the symptoms as checkboxes that return the number 1 if checked  How can I make the last column which is status count the 1s on the entries and return the status whether negative or positive ?

The result would be like this

```
[ID , Student , symptoms1 , symptom2 , symptom3 ,Status]
[1234 Scott   , 1.        , 1.       , 1.       , positive]
```

I tried this but it still results in an error for the right parenthesis

```
create table covid(ID NUMBER(7) , NAME VARCHAR2(32) ,DEPT VARCHAR2(16) , FEVER NUMBER(1) , 
COUGH NUMBER(1) ,TIREDNESS NUMBER(1) ,SHORT_BREATH NUMBER(1) ,SORE_THROAT NUMBER(1) ,
CHEST_PAIN NUMBER(1) ,LOSE_SENSES NUMBER(1),RUNNY_NOSE NUMBER(1), TEST_DATE DATE ,
SYMPTOMS NUMBER(16) ,
CASE
WHEN SYMPTOMS>= 3 THEN 'POSITIVE' ELSE 'NEGATIVE'
END AS RESULT);
```

Comment: Is the status 'positive' if only one of the symptoms is marked as 1, or do all three symptoms need to be marked as 1?

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like symptoms1 + symptoms2 + symptoms3 would give you the sum...

Comment: I think you should remove the case expression in your creating table statement. At this stage just create a column named 'result' as a varchar data. And later the values of this column can be added with 'insert' statement. And you have to insert values for all other columns anyway. So don't  combine two steps in one

Answer (score 0):

One way, but as you did not say how to evaluate the status based on the different combinations of symptomps, you need to put whatever your logic dictates

```
select id , student ,
case when symptoms1 = 1 and symptom2 = 1 and symptom3 =1 then 'POSITIVE' 
     when symptoms1 = 1 and symptom2 = 1 and symptom3 =0 then 'XXXXXXXX'
     when symptoms1 = 1 and symptom2 = 0 and symptom3 =1 then 'XXXXXXXX'
     when symptoms1 = 1 and symptom2 = 0 and symptom3 =0 then 'XXXXXXXX'
     when symptoms1 = 0 and symptom2 = 1 and symptom3 =1 then 'XXXXXXXX'
     when symptoms1 = 0 and symptom2 = 0 and symptom3 =1 then 'XXXXXXXX'
     when symptoms1 = 0 and symptom2 = 1 and symptom3 =0 then 'XXXXXXXX'
     when symptoms1 = 0 and symptom2 = 0 and symptom3 =0 then 'NEGATIVE'
 end as status
 from table
```